# Using Unity Editor, how do i upload a file from my computer and have it appear on a 3D object or plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I found a tutorial on YouTube that accurately added File Explorer and image upload to a 'RawImage' on a canvas using Unity 2017.3.1f1.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is add the same image after 'button press' to a 3D object like a cube or plane as shown by the colored cube. When I run the below code, it registers as being present on the cube but doesn't render. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;

public class Explorer : MonoBehaviour
{
    string path;
    public RawImage image;

    public void OpenExplorer()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with png", "", "png");
        GetImage();
    }

    void GetImage()
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            UpdateImage();
        }
    }
    void UpdateImage()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + path);
        image.texture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tiny bug in your code. It should work sometimes and fail other times. The chances of it working or not depends on the size of the image. It will work if the image is really small but fail when it is a large image.

The reason for this is because of the code in your `UpdateImage` function. The `WWW` is supposed to be used in a coroutine function because you need to yield or wait for it to finish loading or downloading the file before accessing the texture with `www.texture`. Your are not doing this now. Change it to a coroutine function then yield it and it should work fine,.

```
void GetImage()
{
    if (path != null)
    {
        StartCoroutine(UpdateImage());
    }
}

IEnumerator UpdateImage()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + path);
    yield return www;
    image.texture = www.texture;
}
```

---

If some reason you can't use a coroutine because it's an Editor plugin then forget about the `WWW` API and use use `File.ReadAllBytes` to read the image.

```
void GetImage()
{
    if (path != null)
    {
        UpdateImage();
    }
}

void UpdateImage()
{
    byte[] imgByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    texture.LoadImage(imgByte);

    image.texture = texture;
}
```

To assign the image to a 3D Object, get the `MeshRenderer` then set the texture to the `mainTexture` of the material the renderer is using:

```
//Drag the 3D Object here
public MeshRenderer mRenderer;

void UpdateImage()
{
    byte[] imgByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    texture.LoadImage(imgByte);

    mRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll add the complete script below. Drop me your venmo or payment method and I'll send a few bucks for your good deed.

Comment: Thanks for being generous . If you find my answer useful and want to repay me then you just answer any question on SO you think you can answer. You don't have to but that's the best way to repay people when they help you. You are welcome!

Comment: @Hulk Not sure why you unaccepted my answer. You copied what's in my answer and put it as an answer then accepted it? If someone helps you and solve you problem,you accept their answer. There is no need to copy their answer then accept it.

Comment: I don’t remember unaccepting an answer. I added my code as an additional answer. I didn’t realize it was limited to one answer and overrides the other. Honest mistake.

Comment: If you could help with this question, Hulk would appreciate it. I'm trying to make each individual cube in the prefab have its own image rendered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287084/upload-image-to-individual-gameobjects-children-of-prefab?noredirect=1#comment87591074_50287084

Comment: You can add as many answer as you would but you click on the checkmark on the answer, it will accept/unaccept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;


public class Explorer : MonoBehaviour 

{
string path;
public MeshRenderer mRenderer;

public void OpenExplorer()
{
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with png", "", "png");
        GetImage();
}

void GetImage()
{
    if (path != null)
    {
        UpdateImage();
    }
}
    void UpdateImage()
{
    byte[] imgByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (2, 2);
    texture.LoadImage(imgByte);

    mRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture;

    //WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + path);
    //yield return www;
    //image.texture = texture;
    }

}
```